# Dynamic Label from Mvc Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'am having a model like this:

```
public class People()
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get;set;}

  [Display(Name="DynamicName")]
  public string Name {get;set;}

  public bool IsTeacher {get;set;}
  public bool IsStudent {get;set;}
  public bool IsContact {get;set;}
}
```

I am using the above class for multiple Area, using _layout.cshtml my purpose for dynamic menu is solved, like somewhere Teacher somewhere Faculty and so on.

I am using strongly type html helper for displaying label, I need to display Teacher, Faculty, Name etc for the Name Field dynamically which should populate from model level.

to do that, i want somthing like below:

```
    public class People()
    {
    string type = "";
    public People(sting type)
    {
       this.type = type;
    }

      [Key]
      public int Id {get;set;}

      [Display(Name=type)]
      public string Name {get;set;}

      public bool IsTeacher {get;set;}
      public bool IsStudent {get;set;}
      public bool IsContact {get;set;}
    }
```

Can anyone pls help me on this? or any better suggestion to accomplish it?

Pls make sure your solution should not use session.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, Model.NameLabel, ...)`

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster, but in page level nothing can be change i.e. @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name) need to do from Model level as the same view will be use for multiple purpose.

Comment: No,that is not possible. Attributes are metadata and must be know at compile time.

Comment: Thanks Stephen Muecke, can you suggest any alternet solution?

Comment: @raju1208, If you want to notify someone, start the message as this one does. Your alternative to to use the code suggested by CodeCaster